# Swap axis for a linspace plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function with an histogram, plotted like this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lin = np.linspace(min(foo), max(foo), len(foo))
plt.plot(lin, bar)
plt.hist(bar, density=True, bins=100, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Where `foo` and `bar` are simple arrays.

[image: Histogram with function]

However, I would want to have the whole thing in a vertical way... I could add `orientation='horizontal'` to the histogram, but it would not change the function (and from what I have seen, there is nothing similar for a `plot` -> obviously it wouldn't be a function then, but a curve). Otherwise, I could add `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` somewhere, but the same problem resides : `plot` is used for functions, so the swap of it does... well, that :

[image: After inverting the axis]

So, the only way I have now is to manually turn the whole original picture by 90 degrees, but then the axis are turned too and will no longer be on the left and bottom (obviously).

So, have you another idea ? Maybe I should try something else than `plt.plot` ?

EDIT : In the end, I would want something like the image below, but with axes made right. [image]

Comment: I will edit with the image I would want

Comment: You can just swap your x and y....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a plot of y vs x, you can swap axes by swapping arrays:

```
plt.plot(bar, lin)
```

There's no special feature because it's supported out of the box. As you've discovered, plotting a transposed histogram can be accomplished by passing in

```
orientation='horizontal'
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any `matplotlib` method dealing with the issue. You can rotate the curve in a purely mathematical way, i.e. do it through the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). In this simple case it is sufficient to just exchange variables `x` and `y` but in general it looks like this (let's take a parabola for a clear example):

```
rotation = lambda angle: np.array([[ np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)],
                          [np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]])

x = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
y = -x**2

matrix = np.vstack([x,y]).T

rotated_matrix = matrix @ rotation(np.deg2rad(90))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(rotated_matrix[:,0], rotated_matrix[:,1])
ax[1].plot(x,y)
```

[image]

```
rotated_matrix = matrix @ rotation(np.deg2rad(-45))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(rotated_matrix[:,0], rotated_matrix[:,1])
ax[1].plot(x,y)
```

[image]